# Timeout for WaitGroup.Wait()

Tags: go, concurrency, timeout

What is an idiomatic way to assign a timeout to [WaitGroup.Wait()](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Wait) ?

The reason I want to do this, is to safeguard my 'scheduler' from potentially awaiting an errant 'worker' for ever. This leads to some philosophical questions (i.e. how can the system reliably continue once it has errant workers?), but I think that's out of scope for this question.

I have an answer which I'll provide. Now that I've written it down, it doesn't seem so bad but it still feels more convoluted than it ought to. I'd like to know if there's something available which is simpler, more idiomatic, or even an alternative approach which doesn't use WaitGroups.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Mostly your solution you posted [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32840688/1705598) is as good as it can get. Couple of tips to improve it:

- Alternatively you may close the channel to signal completion instead of sending a value on it, a receive operation on a closed channel [can always proceed immediately](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator).
- And it's better to use `defer` statement to signal completion, it is executed even if a function terminates abruptly.
- Also if there is only one "job" to wait for, you can completely omit the `WaitGroup` and just send a value or close the channel when job is complete (the same channel you use in your `select` statement).
- Specifying 1 second duration is as simple as: `timeout := time.Second`. Specifying 2 seconds for example is: `timeout := 2 * time.Second`. You don't need the conversion, `time.Second` is already of type [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration), multiplying it with an untyped constant like `2` will also yield a value of type `time.Duration`.

I would also create a helper / utility function wrapping this functionality. Note that `WaitGroup` must be passed as a pointer else the copy will not get "notified" of the `WaitGroup.Done()` calls. Something like:

```
// waitTimeout waits for the waitgroup for the specified max timeout.
// Returns true if waiting timed out.
func waitTimeout(wg *sync.WaitGroup, timeout time.Duration) bool {
    c := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        defer close(c)
        wg.Wait()
    }()
    select {
    case <-c:
        return false // completed normally
    case <-time.After(timeout):
        return true // timed out
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
if waitTimeout(&wg, time.Second) {
    fmt.Println("Timed out waiting for wait group")
} else {
    fmt.Println("Wait group finished")
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/1TdOU_PquM).

Comment: thanks, very thorough answer. I eventually stopped using a WaitGroup altogether, and used a single channel instead. My code ended up simpler, clearer and 'less problematic'. My code could count the number of iterations, so I could use the select statement a fixed number of times, then use a single NewTimer for the timeout. For completeness I'll add another answer in due course.

Comment: So, a little FYI since this just popped up in #go-nuts: This will *not* work if the `wg.Add` calls are *inside a goroutine*. Just commenting in case somebody uses this code in a similar fashion to the issue #go-nuts just resolved!

Comment: if `wg.Wait()` never return, does it leaked a goroutine?

Comment: @coanor If `wg.Wait()` never returns, then obviously the goroutine calling it is blocked forever. Whether it's a leak depends on the context. E.g. `http.ListenAndServe()` also never returns if there is no error, you still don't consider it as a goroutine leak.

Comment: If the Wait() blocked forever, It will leak a goroutine when waitTimeout has been called. But no other better solution has been find.

Comment: @coanor At least you could `panic` your `main` and/or notify user/system, instead of waiting indefinately.

Comment: Why is this accepted as an answer as there is a potential goroutine leak if  wg.Wait() could never return.

Comment: you can fix the leak by looping and calling wg.Done in the case timeout block, then the goroutine will release the close(c) and the process will exit normally.  A little optimisation could reduce the timeout to a shorter interval after the first iteration.

Comment: This solution only helps in not blocking the main routine in case context timeout but doesn't solve routine leak problem when Wait is blocked.

Answer (score 7):

I did it like this: http://play.golang.org/p/eWv0fRlLEC

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    c <- struct{}{}
}()
timeout := time.Duration(1) * time.Second
fmt.Printf("Wait for waitgroup (up to %s)\n", timeout)
select {
case <-c:
    fmt.Printf("Wait group finished\n")
case <-time.After(timeout):
    fmt.Printf("Timed out waiting for wait group\n")
}
fmt.Printf("Free at last\n")
```

It works fine, but is it *the best way to do it*?

Answer (score 6):

Most existing answers suggest leaking goroutines. The idiomatic way to assign a timeout to [WaitGroup.Wait](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Wait) is to use underlying [sync/atomic](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) package primitives. I took code from @icza answer and rewrote it using the `atomic` package, and added context cancelation as that's an idiomatic way to notify of a timeout.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var submitCount int32
    // run this instead of wg.Add(1)
    atomic.AddInt32(&submitCount, 1)

    // run this instead of wg.Done()
    // atomic.AddInt32(&submitCount, -1)

    timeout := time.Second
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
    defer cancel()
    fmt.Printf("Wait for waitgroup (up to %s)\n", timeout)

    waitWithCtx(ctx, &submitCount)

    fmt.Println("Free at last")
}

// waitWithCtx returns when passed counter drops to zero
// or when context is cancelled
func waitWithCtx(ctx context.Context, counter *int32) {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(10 * time.Millisecond)
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        case <-ticker.C:
            if atomic.LoadInt32(counter) == 0 {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Same code in Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_FHOnHSExtD)

Comment: if `atomic.AddInt32(&submitCount, 1)` were the idiomatic way of incrementing the wait group instead of `wg.Add(1)` it would be suggested here https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups

Comment: Imho this is actually a counter-pattern as it represents an active wait, i.e. polling

Answer (score 4):

This is a bad idea. **Do not abandon goroutines**, doing so may introduce races, resource leaks and unexpected conditions, ultimately impacting the stability of your application.

Instead use timeouts throughout your code consistently in order to make sure no goroutine is blocked forever or takes too long to run.

The idiomatic way for achieving that is via [`context.WithTimeout()`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithTimeout):

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5 * time.Second)
defer cancel()

// Now perform any I/O using the given ctx:
go func() {
  err = example.Connect(ctx)
  if err != nil { /* handle err and exit goroutine */ }
  . . .
}()
```

Now you can safely use `WaitGroup.Wait()`, knowing it will always finish in a timely manner.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution without leaking `wg.Wait()` routine: just use (well-suported and widely-used) [`golang.org/x/sync/semaphore`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/semaphore):

- Instead of `sync.WaitGroup{}` use `sem.NewWeighted(N)` (you have to know `N` in advance)
- Instead of `wg.Add(1)` use `err := sem.Acquire(ctx, 1)`
- Instead of `defer wg.Done()` use `defer sem.Release(1)`
- Instead of `wg.Wait()` you can use `sem.Acquire(ctx, N)` with context with timeout.
- Watch out, this is only equivalent to `sync.WaitGroup` in this specific use-case (when you only call `Add(1)` and `Release(1)` `N` times). Read the documentation carefully.

[Example](https://play.golang.org/p/Bs74BYTeHbz):

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/sync/semaphore"
)

func worker(n int) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(n) * time.Second)
    log.Printf("Worker %v finished", n)
}

func main() {

    const N = 5
    sem := semaphore.NewWeighted(N)

    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {

        err := sem.Acquire(context.Background(), 1)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("sem.Acquire err", err)
        }
        go func(n int) {
            defer sem.Release(1)
            worker(n)
        }(i)
    }

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*2)
    defer cancel()

    err := sem.Acquire(ctx, N)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("sem.Acquire err:", err)
        return
    }

    log.Println("sem.Acquire ok")
}
```

Which results in:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Worker 0 finished
2009/11/10 23:00:01 Worker 1 finished
2009/11/10 23:00:02 Worker 2 finished
2009/11/10 23:00:02 sem.Acquire err: context deadline exceeded
```

Answer (score 4):

Throwing in a solution which does not leak a goroutine, or rely on polling (sleeps):

```golang
import "atomic"

type WaitGroup struct {
    count int32
    done chan struct{}
}

func NewWaitGroup() *WaitGroup {
    return &WaitGroup{
        done: make(chan struct{}),
    }
}

func (wg *WaitGroup) Add(i int32) {
    select {
    case <-wg.done:
        panic("use of an already closed WaitGroup")
    default:
    }
    atomic.AddInt32(&wg.count, i)
}

func (wg *WaitGroup) Done() {
    i := atomic.AddInt32(&wg.count, -1)
    if i == 0 {
        close(wg.done)
    }
    if i < 0 {
        panic("too many Done() calls")
    }
}

func (wg *WaitGroup) C() <-chan struct{} {
    return wg.done
}
```

Usage:

```golang
wg := NewWaitGroup()
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
  // do stuff
  wg.Done()
}

select {
case <-wg.C():
  fmt.Printf("Completed!\n")
case <-time.After(time.Second):
  fmt.Printf("Timed out!\n")
}
```

Comment: Great answer! `case <-time.NewTimer(time.Second)` is invalid, I suppose you meant `case <-time.After(time.Second)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The following will **not introduce any leaking goroutines**

```
func callingFunc() {
    ...
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    for _, msg := range msgs {
        wg.Add(1)
        go wrapperParallelCall(ctx, params, wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}

func wrapperParallelCall(ctx, params, wg) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second)
    defer wg.Done()
    defer cancel()

    originalSequenceCall(ctx, params)
}

func originalSequenceCall(ctx, params) {...}
```

Comment: You could use a single context for all the tasks by creating the context in callingFunc instead of wrapperParallelCall.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library that encapsulates the concurrency logic https://github.com/shomali11/parallelizer which you can also pass a timeout.

Here is an example without a timeout:

```
func main() {
    group := parallelizer.DefaultGroup()

    group.Add(func() {
        for char := 'a'; char < 'a'+3; char++ {
            fmt.Printf("%c ", char)
        }
    })

    group.Add(func() {
        for number := 1; number < 4; number++ {
            fmt.Printf("%d ", number)
        }
    })

    err := group.Run()

    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("Done")
    fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
}
```

Output:

```
a 1 b 2 c 3 
Done
Error: <nil>
```

Here is an example with a timeout:

```
func main() {
    options := &parallelizer.Options{Timeout: time.Second}
    group := parallelizer.NewGroup(options)

    group.Add(func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Minute)

        for char := 'a'; char < 'a'+3; char++ {
            fmt.Printf("%c ", char)
        }
    })

    group.Add(func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Minute)

        for number := 1; number < 4; number++ {
            fmt.Printf("%d ", number)
        }
    })

    err := group.Run()

    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("Done")
    fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
}
```

Output:

```
Done
Error: timeout
```

Comment: This is leaking goroutines: nothing stops the tasks from running beyond the duration the launcher waits.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an actual answer to this question but was the (much simpler) solution to my little problem when I had this question.

My 'workers' were doing http.Get() requests so I just set the timeout on the http client.

```
urls := []string{"http://1.jpg", "http://2.jpg"}
wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
for _, url := range urls {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(url string) {
        client := http.Client{
            Timeout: time.Duration(3 * time.Second), // only want very fast responses
        }
        resp, err := client.Get(url)
        //... check for errors
        //... do something with the image when there are no errors
        //...

        wg.Done()
    }(url)

}
wg.Wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same need for one of our systems. by passing a context to goroutines and closing that context when we are facing timeout, we would prevent goroutine leaks.

```
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctxWithCancel, cancelFunc := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    Provide(ctxWithCancel, 5, &wg)
    Provide(ctxWithCancel, 5, &wg)
    c := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        c <- struct{}{}
        fmt.Println("closed")
    }()

    select {
    case <-c:
    case <-time.After(20 * time.Millisecond):
        cancelFunc()
        fmt.Println("timeout")
    }
}

func Work(ctx context.Context, to int) {
    for i := 0; i < to; i++ {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        default:
            fmt.Println(i)
            time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
}

func Provide(ctx context.Context, to int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        Work(ctx, to)
        wg.Done()
    }()
}
```

Comment: This is leaking goroutines: if a worker works too long without checking for the context expiration, main will stop waiting for it after the timeout, but the worker will still be running. A non-leaking implementation would wait even beyond the timer.